# Writing generic XML Parser

Tags: iphone

I want to create the generic XML parser so that I want to reuse much of code
Use case is I have to parse 10 XML web servers, and all of them have different data So How can i create generic XML Parser so that i use most of the parsing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the many XML libraries, such as TouchXML or Google's. These will parse documents into object trees, among other things.

Comment: Do you mean I can parse multiple documents with just one class?

Comment: Sure, why not? You parse documents into dictionaries/arrays or true XML nodes and iterate over, or search, the datastructures you get back. Then you only have to write different search/iteration logic for each document type.

Answer (score 2):

[Using libxml2 for XML parsing and XPath queries in Cocoa](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html)

Comment: But I have to write each class and implement methods of NSXMLParser for every document

Comment: Or, instead, you could write *one* parser, and several XPath statements for the data in each XML file. 10 XPath statements and one parser are much easier to write than 10 XPath statements and 10 parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSXmlParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) I think it helps you !

Comment: But I have to write each class and implement methods of NSXMLParser for every document